# OpenGL: strange thing with depth and text rendering

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl, depth-buffer, text

**TL;DR** I render a scene with M,V,P matrices as always. Than I render something (in this case - text) without any matrices and using separate shaders pair on coordinates with Z = -1. Somehow it's rendered closer to the camera than something on coordinates with Z = 0.9. I can't understand why.

Here is something I can't figure out.

Consider this vertex shader which is used for text rendering:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec2 vertexPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertexUV;

out vec2 fragmentUV;

void main() {
    fragmentUV = vertexUV;

    gl_Position.x = vertexPos.x*2 - 1;
    gl_Position.y = vertexPos.y*2 - 1;
    gl_Position.z = -1.0;
    gl_Position.w =  1.0;
}
```

When text is rendered with Z  = -1 everything looks fine:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ShCYqqU.png]

And if I change Z to 0.9 scene looks like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/RhPtHG9.png]

According to [this tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/) perspective matrix modifies the scene so that all visible objects are in cube where -1 <= {X,Y,Z} <= 1. Also by default camera looks "down" towards Z axis.

So shouldn't it be conversely: larger Z - closer to the camera?

Full source code [is on GitHub](https://github.com/afiskon/c-opengl-text). [Here](https://github.com/afiskon/c-opengl-text/blob/master/demo/main.c#L784) is a code which renders text. And [this code](https://github.com/afiskon/c-opengl-text/blob/master/demo/main.c#L347) fills corresponding VBO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mystery solved. I was not aware of the fact that OpenGL expects vertex shader output to be left-handed. And that it *is* usually left-handed after multiplying coordinates to projection matrix (see [this article](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html)). So smaller Z in vertex shader - closer to the camera.

And here is a great cheat sheet about left-handed and right-handed coordinates:

[image: http://image.slidesharecdn.com/06gfxmath-120207173111-phpapp01/95/cs-354-graphics-math-27-728.jpg]